# Outlook 365 won't let me manually configure servers

Tags: outlook, office365

I am trying to add my personal email account to Outlook 365.

My email and DNS are hosted by Bluehost. The mail server is a shared host and its certificates are on the bluehost.com domain. When I enter my email address, whether I select manual setup or not, Outlook sets up my mailbox automatically, not letting me configure server and encryption settings. I've always been able to set these up manually on prior installations. How Can I enter server information and set SSL for SMTP and IMAP?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming question, it belongs at SuperUser.
That begin said, you can still use the old account UI in the Mail Control Panel applet.